# Angular 2 undefined var on eval

Tags: javascript, angular, ionic-framework, ionic2

So I have the following code:

```
@ViewChild('MondayPicker') MondayPicker;
@ViewChild('TuesdayPicker') TuesdayPicker;
@ViewChild('WednesdayPicker') WednesdayPicker;
@ViewChild('ThursdayPicker') ThursdayPicker;
@ViewChild('FridayPicker') FridayPicker;
@ViewChild('SaturdayPicker') SaturdayPicker;
@ViewChild('SundayPicker') SundayPicker;

working_days = ['Monday','Tuesday','Wednesday','Thursday','Friday','Saturday','Sunday'];
simpleColumns;
reservation_times;
currentUser;
private ngUnsubscribe: Subject<any> = new Subject<any>()

ionViewDidEnter(){

    for(var i = 0; i < this.working_days.length; i++){
        this.firebase.database.list('/schedule',{query: {orderByChild: 'user_day',equalTo: this.currentUser.uid+'_'+this.working_days[i] }})
        .take(1)
        .subscribe(
        (data) => {
            console.log(eval('this.'+data[0].day+'Picker.setValue("From 00: 00 TO 00: 00");'));
        });
    }
}
```

Now this line:

> console.log(eval('this.'+data[0].day+'Picker.setValue("From 00: 00 TO
>   00: 00");'));

So what I'm trying to do will produce this: `this.MondayPicker.setValue("From 00: 00 TO
00: 00");`

But I get `undefined` on `this.MondayPicker` for example, but If I do manually `this.MondayPicker.setValue("From 00: 00 TO
00: 00");` it works, why is this happening?

Comment: Thank you!! Post it as an answer so I can accept it, I'm new to this so I didn't knew it will work.

Comment: I suspect that the root of the problem is that when you run the Eval, the evaluated script has a different scope and in that scope, 'this' is no longer what you think it is.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I think you should avoid using `eval`. Try this instead:

```
this[data[0].day + 'Picker'].setValue(...)
```

Comment: I will accept it in 7 minutes, so in JS this is basically an array with objects?

Comment: It depends on what you send from firebase